# Assignment of char value causing a Bus error

Tags: c, char

The function is to reverse a C string:

```
void reverse(char[] str){

char *start = str;
char *end = str;
char tmp;

if (str) {

    while (*end) {
        end++;
    }

    end--;

    while (&str > &end) {

        tmp = *str;

        *str = *end;
        str++;
        *end=tmp;
        end--;
       }
    }

}
```

In the last while loop, when I assign *end to *str, this line is causing a bus error, Could anyone please explain why?

btw, what is the difference between a
 char[] temp    and   char temp[]?

Comment: it's generally considered good form to post the full text of the error

Comment: How do you call `reverse`?

Comment: The difference between `char[] temp` and `char temp[]` is that the latter is valid C and the former isn't.  Your code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: `&str > &end` -- what makes you think you want the addresses of the pointers? (You don't.) "the difference between a char[] temp and char temp[]?" One is legal C and the other isn't.

Comment: @SamIam "bus error" is plenty clear enough. The "full text" will give the address where it happened, which won't help us any -- we were told what line of code it happens on (which is obvious to anyone who knows enough C to be competent to respond to this).

Comment: "How do you call reverse? " --Irrelevant. It's always going to either be a noop or crash, depending on the relationship between  the array address and the current stack ptr.

Comment: OP: **Do not edit your code in place** -- it invalidates the comments and answers. If you want to do an update, add a separate section.

Comment: "I assign *end to *str, this line is causing a bus error" -- No it isn't ... not in your edited code ... because that line cannot ever get executed.

Comment: I mean after I changed the greater sign to smaller. The while loop gets to be executed, The program crashes on that line, Do you have any ideas?

Comment: See Basile's question above. Perhaps you're trying to reverse a string literal ... that's common among the thousands of newbies who post their reverse code to SO.

Comment: I've rolled back your edits, as you've changed the context of the entire question by changing the code. Please don't do that, because it makes the answers you've received look like they don't apply. If you have serious problems in what you've posted, delete your question (or ask the moderators to do so by flagging it) and post a new question. It's much harder for people to hit a target you keep moving, and making substantial changes after you've gotten answers makes the people who've already answered look foolish.

Answer (score 3):

This loop condition:

```
while (&str > &end)
```

is wrong.  You don't want the `&` operators, and you also have it backwards.  Use:

```
while (str < end)
```

Besides that, as I mentioned in my comment above, you need to declare your function signature properly, too:

```
void reverse(char str[])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
while (&str > &end) {
```

This line is wrong. & yields the address, and the addresses of these pointer variables doesn't change during the loop. You don't want the addresses of the pointers, you want their values, and you want to loop until the start reaches the end, so:

```
while (str < end) {
```

Or

```
while (start < end) {
```

and change the other instances of `str` to `start` as appropriate ... or get rid of your unused `start` variable.

> btw, what is the difference between a char[] temp and char temp[]?

The former isn't legal C.

Update:

The newly posted code looks ok, but its behavior is undefined if the argument is invalid or non-writable ... for example, a string literal. A full answer requires that you post a 
[Short, Self Contained, Compilable Example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Can you explain why that line is causing the bus error in more details?

Comment: Can you explain how your answer is different then Carl's comment and answer?

Comment: @0x90 Can you explain why you're making non-substantive comments? I started writing my answer before Carl's was posted ... it happens often on SO.

Comment: @FangBoy Because &str > &end is either always true or always false, depending on where str is relative to the current stack ... the values don't change during your loop, so either the loop doesn't run or it runs "forever" and you crash when str and/or end point to unallocated memory.

Comment: @JimBalter It indeed happens but I think you may add your input to the answer so IMO it is a substantive comment, +1 for the answer on the comment.